# Selection of non-white characters with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

In MS-Word I have text like this: `hif.imp. ינעימשת od שמע`
When I double click on the on the hebrew word the range is selected with the space after the word. I wanted to create macro, that will reduce the white space characters.

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim str1 As String
Set r1 = Selection.Range
r1.SetRange Start:=0, End:=Len(Trim(r1.Text))
```

However when I run this, nothing happens, the selection still includes the space. How to fix this?

Comment: try using `selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1` - if that does not work, try -2 etc.

Comment: `r1.SetRange Start:=0, End:=Len(Trim(r1.Text))` sets a range that points to the same location as the `Selection` but is independent of it. It does nothing to change what is selected. You would need to add `r1.Select` to do that.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Hm, but then Start cannot be 0, it must be the starting position of the selection. `r1.SetRange Start:=r1.Start, End:=Len(Trim(r1.Text))
r1.Select
` Still does not work correctly. Yes, it can select now, but the start position is wrong. Also, It seems that the count of selected characters is wrong.

Comment: Try thinking through what you are doing. The `Start` and `End` parameters of `SetRange` are positions in the document, not your range, i.e. position 0 is the very start of the document. So, when you set the end it needs to be set relative to the start, i.e. start + length of text. You also need to be aware that `Trim` will remove spaces from both ends of the string and could therefore also affect your start position.

Comment: I got it! `r1.SetRange Start:=a, End:=a + b` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Trim` should works as expected. Issue somewhere else.

Minimal working code

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim value1, value2 As String

value1 = sht.Cells(1, 1)

value2 = RTrim(LTrim(value1))
value3 = Trim(Trim(value1))

MsgBox ("'" + value1 + "'" + vbCrLf + "'" + value2 + "'" + vbCrLf + "'" + value3 + "'")
```

Result from value2 is equal to result from value3

[image]

Comment: Question is on MS-Word application.

Comment: VBA is the same -- in Excel in Word and in Access.... Ok. Let me check it with Word...

Answer (score 0):

Code for the Word:

Double click on the word, then run the macro. This should select text only.

```
Sub Makro2()
Dim r1 As Range
Dim str1 As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Set r1 = Selection.Range
str1 = Trim(r1.Text)
a = r1.Start
b = Len(Trim(r1.Text))
r1.SetRange Start:=a, End:=a + b
r1.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively just press Shift+Left Arrow to move the end of the selection back.